# Updating web redirect uri of Azure AD app registration

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a scenario where my pipeline should update the app registration with an additional redirectUrl.
I have managed to extract the current web.redirectUris with the following:

`existing_urls=$(az ad app show --id '<client-id>' --query "[web.redirectUris]" --output tsv)`

I would like to achieve something like this

```
existing_urls=$(az ad app show --id '<client-id>' --query "[web.redirectUris]" --output tsv)
az ad app update --id '<client-id>' --web-redirect-uris "$existing_urls https://hostname.com/newCallback"
```

I have tried updating the web.redirectUris in two ways and both of them have failed when I pass multiple redirect URIs.

**Attempt 1**

```
az ad app update --id '<client-id>' --web-redirect-uris "https://hostname.com/callbackx https://hostname.com/callbacky"

One or more properties contains invalid values.
```

However when having only one uri this worked fine

```
az ad app update --id '<client-id>' --web-redirect-uris "https://hostname.com/callbackx"
```

**Attempt 2**
This one fails regardless of number of redirectUris that are passed

```
az ad app update --id '<client-id>' --set "web.redirectUris=['https://hostname.com/callbackx', 'https://hostname.com/callbacky']"

Couldn't find 'web' in ''. Available options: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried as shown :But got the same error:

```
az ad app show --id 1e7bxxx7830

existing_urls=$(az ad app show --id 1e7b8fxxxx830 --query "[web.redirectUris]")

az ad app update --id 1e7xxx0a7830 --web-redirect-uris "$existing_urls https://hostname.com/newCallback"

$updated_urls="$existing_urls https://hostname.com/newCallback"

az ad app update --id 1e7b8xxx0a7830  --set "web.redirectUris='$updated_urls'"

az ad app update --id 1e7b8fxxxd0a7830  --set "web.redirectUris='$updated_urls'"
```

**Error:**

```
Couldn't find 'web' in ''. Available options: []
```

[image]

Following command worked foe me in azure cli in updating multiple Redirect Urls:

**`az ad app update --id '1e7bxxxa7830' --web-redirect-uris "https://hostname.com/callback"  "https://jwt.ms" "https://myexampleapp.com"`**

here --id is `clientId` .

[image]

So  give the command with required urls as
az ad app update --id '1e7bxxxa7830' --web-redirect-uris "`<url1>`"  "`<url2>`" "`<url3>`"

upon `az ad app show --id 1e7b8xxxx830`

[image]